# Perl Tk canvas, window titlebar is overlapped the canvas, overrideredirect(1)

Tags: perl, canvas, tk-toolkit

my perl code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new();

$mw->overrideredirect(1);

my $canvas = $mw->Canvas(
    -bg => 'white',
    -width => 410,
)->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);


my $rect_filled = $canvas->createRectangle(
    0, 0, 360, 100,
    -outline => '#C0C0C0',
    -fill => '#FFEC73',
);
$canvas->bind( $rect_filled, '<Enter>' => sub{
    $canvas->itemconfigure( $rect_filled,
        -outline => '#E0E0E0',
        -fill => '#0000ff',
    );
});
$canvas->bind( $rect_filled, '<Leave>' => sub{
    $canvas->itemconfigure( $rect_filled,
        -outline => '#C0C0C0',
        -fill => '#FFEC73',
    );
});


$mw->MainLoop();
```

If I run this code, i can see the yellow rectangle. But, when I move the mouse into the canvas from above, the ENTER-event comes only after ~30 pixels, seen in the screenshot.

[image: canvas no enter event]
[image: canvas enter event]

It seems as if the titlebar is still above the canvas.

How can I stop this behavior so that the ENTER-event is also raised from the coordinates (0,0)?

--
**Update for question:**

- Debian 8.11
- Gnome 3.14.1
- Perl 5.20.2
- Tk 804.032

Comment: It does not seem to be a problem with Perl. If I convert your script to a [Tcl script](https://pastebin.com/kyqx4RiX) it shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround after read this:

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/Wm.pod#BUGS

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new();

# $mw->overrideredirect(1); #

my $canvas = $mw->Canvas(
    -bg => 'white',
    -width => 410,
)->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);


my $rect_filled = $canvas->createRectangle(
    0, 0, 360, 100,
    -outline => '#C0C0C0',
    -fill => '#FFEC73',
);
$canvas->bind( $rect_filled, '<Enter>' => sub{
    $canvas->itemconfigure( $rect_filled,
        -outline => '#E0E0E0',
        -fill => '#0000ff',
    );
});
$canvas->bind( $rect_filled, '<Leave>' => sub{
    $canvas->itemconfigure( $rect_filled,
        -outline => '#C0C0C0',
        -fill => '#FFEC73',
    );
});

# workarround, delay call overrideredirect(1)
$mw->after( 1, sub{
    $mw->overrideredirect(1);
    $mw->withdraw();
    $mw->deiconify();
    print "set\n";
});

$mw->MainLoop();
```

But is this the right way?